# Dismissing the keyboard with UISearchBar, without resigning first responder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

Hey, I was working on a navigation-based app on iPhone similar to the contacts app.  When you input something in the search bar, and scroll in the table (in the contacts app), the keyboard goes away.  I don't think it resigns first responder though, because when I try and do that in -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView, it disables the cancel button, which does not happen in the contacts app.  Basically my question is how do I dismiss the keyboard without disabling the cancel button, like in the contacts app?

Thanks

Comment: WOW.  Haha, the tutorial I used did not use a searchdisplaycontroller, for whatever reason...  Using that makes it do exactly what I want.  It's funny, because I even matched the darknesssuffering of the overlay that happens when you start searching, but now it happens twice, so it gets really dark.

Answer (score 7):

Well, just ran into this very old question. 
You can enable the 'cancel' button when you start to scroll as follows:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    let searchCancelButton = searchBar.valueForKey("cancelButton") as! UIButton
    searchCancelButton.enabled = true // <-- THIS line is the trick

}
```

**Swift 4**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as! UIButton
    cancelButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag` to `viewDidLoad()` worked like a charm.

Comment: cancel button stayed disabled when I tried this one unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

(As hinted at in the self-answering comment) If you want to get table search behavior like the built-in contacts app, you can't just slap a UISearchBar into a view with a UITableView, instead you need to use a UITableViewController together with a `Search Display Controller`.   This sample app is a perfect guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple options but all the desired output is not achieved,  like hiding the cancel along with keyboard.

So I used `searchBar.inputAccessoryView` which will be visible above the keyboard  with a button at right (toolbar).

```
    class AnyViewClass{

        func createSearch(){
            searchBar.inputAccessoryView = ViewsFactory.createAccessoryView(withButtonType:.done,target: self, action:#selector(YourClass.keyboardDonePressed))
        }


        @objc private func keyboardDonePressed(){
             searchBar?.resignFirstResponder()
             searchBar?.text = nil
        }

}

class ViewsFactory {

    class func createAccessoryView(withButtonType type:UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem,
                                   target: Any?,
                                   action: Selector?) -> UIToolbar{

        var accessoryDoneButton: UIBarButtonItem!
        let accessoryToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                       y: 0,
                                                       width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                                                       height: 44))

        let emptySpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
                                         target: nil,
                                         action: nil)
        accessoryDoneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done,
                                              target: target,
                                              action: action)
        accessoryDoneButton.tintColor = <any color>
        accessoryToolBar.items = [emptySpace, accessoryDoneButton]
        return accessoryToolBar

    }
}
```